ARMA estimation before GJR-GARCH. How to proceed with multiple time-series?
I want to study the Conditional Variance of various crypto-currencies returns series (13, of which 5 meme, 8 "serious"). Since my main focus is the asymmetric response of the variance against past returns I am using a GJR-GARCH model.
Doing a Ljung-box test I noticed how autocorrelation is detected only on 3 of my 13 currency sample.
These are my doubts:

Before estimating the GJR-GARCH, should I apply an ARMA model to all time-series regardless of autocorrelation and then work on the residuals, or should I apply an ARMA only to the autocorrelated series and work directly on the returns on the non autocorrelated ones?

Should I tailor the Arma model to each series through AIC/BIC or should I apply the same model to all series to treat them equally (i'm 99% sure i should not treat them equally, but that 1% bugs me).


Consider that the point of this analisys would be to compare the variance response and the laverage of all 13 cryptos with each other
Thank you for any help!
